# SQLException: Exhausted Resultset oracle11g

Tags: java, jdbc, oracle11g

my code is  :

```
        Statement testSt = null;
        ResultSet rset = null;
        String query = "select jid FROM playjdbc WHERE jid=56";
        try {
            testSt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_SENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

            if (!testSt.execute(query)) {
                System.out.println("jid doesnt exist!");
            } else {

                rset = testSt.getResultSet();
                rset.first();
                int jidValue = rset.getInt(1); // exception cause
                System.out.println("jid is = " + jidValue);

            }

        }
```

rset.getInt(1) line causing this exception , but 
when i ran same query in my database it returned data .

stack trace :

```
java.sql.SQLException: Exhausted Resultset
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.ScrollableResultSet.getOracleObject(ScrollableResultSet.java:623)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.ScrollableResultSet.getInt(ScrollableResultSet.java:776)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.UpdatableResultSet.getInt(UpdatableResultSet.java:666)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The boolean result from `Statement.execute()` is false if the statement returns an update count or if the statement is of a type that does not return a `ResultSet`.  The Javadoc is slightly ambiguous in its language.

Instead of `rset.first()` you need to do

```
if (rset.next())
{
    int jidValue = rset.getInt(1); // exception cause
    System.out.println("jid is = " + jidValue);
}
```

`rset.first()` is used only when moving back to the first row in a ResultSet that is not `FORWARD_ONLY`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this code is wrong in every way.  I'd read the [JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/) and follow the idioms you find in it.

Comment: well i followed the same tutorial and example i am trying is present in this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/transactions.html

Answer (score 0):

Just try removing the `rset.first();` line.... try that it might work.. i never used rset.first();